# "control userpasswords2" in Run box

Tags: windows-10, laptop, security, user-accounts

When a home user woke their laptop (HP with Windows 10, Office, Defender, Chrome, a few games) this morning, it went straight to the desktop (no password prompt) and the Run command box was open with "control userpasswords2" in it. Nothing else was open.

The computer was used yesterday for routine web surfing, then lid closed. No one had physical access overnight (let's assume a Mission Impossible style break-in did not occur).

Any ideas how that got there, or what to look for? Is there some macro that might cause this? Or is it a remote intrusion?

Comment: So, you caught it before someone locked you out of your own system, but they probably also created an admin account for themselves.  A bet is that the system isn't set to actually -sleep- when you close the lid, and you don't have any security software running because you figure you don't need it.  I sure hope you didn't also have credit card numbers written into some plain-text file.

Comment: Adding to all this, the information given and the assumptions that can reasonably drawn from them strongly indicate that your organization needs to take security much more seriously and should likely pay good money to find and retain qualified individuals or services that can help fill this need for you. This time you may have gotten off easily, and it would be far better to take this *gentle* warning and fix the problems than it would be to experience a full breach the next time and hurt people and your organization if you fail to take those necessary precautions.

Comment: To clarify: this is a non-business laptop belonging to an acquaintance who I am helping outside of work.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is not what the command line had, but the fact that if that was caused by somebody then they could have done anything (pretty much) that the user account could do - the entry route could have been any vulnerability, or anything that you clicked on - without forensic investigation you can't pin it down.

So, from a basic security best practices perspective you should:

- Format the disk
- Reinstall
- Restore data from backup

If you have network logs you can tell everyone through them to see what happened, but your question makes me think you might not.

Answer (score 1):

Foo Bar specifically asked "any ideas how that got there", not "should I worry about nefarious origins". I just opened MY Run command and "control userpasswords2" is showing. I know nothing of this command, but one thing I am certain of, the last person to use the run command typed it in. In my case, it was an engineer setting up a piece of equipment that utilizes a win 10 PC. I did notice that this computer booted all the way without anyone touching the keyboard. I specifically requested a password access. So I assume what happened in my case was the engineer had removed password for convenience while working, but then forgot to restore before he left. Could be wrong, but a good guess none the less. I do not have any knowledge to help, other than my own experience. I do have a philosophy that helps me, might help you as well.  I'm a no-body, no great wealth, no super secret info or access, not a celebrity with potential gossip material, etc. So I ask myself, why would ANYONE waist there time trying to access anything I might have? And my answer has always been, I have no clue! There is nothing to be gained, so I believe I can sheep at night without worrying. I know this is irrelevant, and this post was some time ago, but just wanted to share. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

My daughter put it there as a security measure. She works on peoples personal accounts and gets secret information and automatically entered the password to my computer.
.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1125698)